# Tanuki Service Wrapper - start jar with application.properties

Tags: java, service, java-service-wrapper, tanuki

I want to wrap a jar that need to read from application.properties. So I have set the application.properties in /opt/Final/lib/conf/application.properties but when I start the service it says:

```
> wrapper  | Launching a JVM... 
> wrapper  | Java Command Line: 
> wrapper  | Command[0] : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java 
> wrapper  | Command[1] : -Djava.library.path=../lib 
> wrapper  | Command[2] : -classpath 
> wrapper  | Command[3] : ../lib/wrapper.jar:/opt/Final/lib/MyApp.jar 
> wrapper  | Command[4] : -Dwrapper.key=e8FXDtWhwLBxcsJ0 
> wrapper  | Command[5] : -Dwrapper.port=32000 
> wrapper  | Command[6] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 
> wrapper  | Command[7] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 
> wrapper  | Command[8] : -Dwrapper.pid=8030 
> wrapper  | Command[9] : -Dwrapper.version=3.5.35 
> wrapper  | Command[10] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper 
> wrapper  | Command[11] : -Dwrapper.arch=x86 
> wrapper  | Command[12] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 
> wrapper  | Command[13] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 
> wrapper  | Command[14] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp
> wrapper  | Command[15] : /opt/Final/lib/MyApp.jar 
> wrapper  | Command[16] : -c 
> wrapper  | Command[17] : /opt/Final/lib/conf jvm 1 
> | WrapperManager: Initializing... jvm 1    | Sorry, unable to find application.properties
```

This is my tanuki configuration:

```
wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=/opt/Final/lib/MyApp.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log
wrapper.app.parameter.1=/opt/Final/lib/MyApp.jar  
wrapper.app.parameter.2=-c
wrapper.app.parameter.3=/opt/Final/lib/conf
```

I have tried to set the app.parameter.3 to /opt/Final/lib/conf/application.properties but it is same...

> Sorry, unable to find application.properties

So what can cause this?